# android how can I approach setRequestProperty in volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

I was using httpurlconnection class now I move to volley how can I put Authorization token

```
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) client._url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + client.Token);
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Does my answer work for your issue or not?

Comment: yes this solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is what I often do in my volley projects:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
       headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
       headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + mAccessToken);
       return headers;
}
```

For basic authentication case:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();                
       String credentials = "username:password";
       String auth = "Basic "
                        + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
       headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
       headers.put("Authorization", auth);
       return headers;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> how can I approach setRequestProperty in volley library

In Volley library [HurlStack](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/com/android/volley/toolbox/HurlStack.java) by using it we can set `setRequestProperty` for connection:

**1.** Create a class by extending `HurlStack` class :

```
public class CustomHurlStack extends HurlStack {
    ...
    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {

       HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + client.Token);

        return connection;
      }
     }
```

**2.** And when creating `RequestQueue` then pass `CustomHurlStack` class object:

```
RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), 
                                                       new CustomHurlStack());
```